# Converting sty and bst files to lyx layout

Tags: packages, lyx-layouts

I want to write a paper for a conference that requires the use of a specific style-sheet, see here: http://www.acl2012.org/call/sub01.asp under "ACL 2012 Style Files".

I would like to use LyX for writing the paper, but, as far as I see, LyX works with `.layout` files.

How can I convert the `acl2012.sty` file to a format that LyX can understand?

Comment: Did you check the LyX help file "Customization", here item 5.2.2? I think this answers your question.

Comment: @vaettchen Can you turn your comment into an answer (maybe expanding it a bit)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from the LyX help file and adapted for the given circumstances:

Start by copying the existing class's layout file into your local directory (I assume the underlying class is `report` and we work in Linux):

```
cp report.layout ~/.lyx/layouts/acl2012.layout
```

Then edit `acl2012.layout` and change the line:

```
\DeclareLaTeXClass{report}
```

to read

```
\DeclareLaTeXClass[report, acl2012.sty]{report (acl2012)}
```

Then add:

```
Preamble     
    \usepackage{acl2012}
EndPreamble
```

near the top of the file.

Start LyX and select `Tools->Reconfigure`. 
Then restart LyX and try creating a new document. 
You should see `report (acl2012)` as a document class option in the `Document->Settings` dialog.

In case of complications (sectioning commands working differently etc.) consult the LyX help file that contains further information.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please add explanation about how to incorporate the bibliography style file - acl.bst ? Usually .sty and .bst files change together, so it makes sense to relate to both of them...

Comment: Have you tried copying the `.bst` file into the same directory where your `.lyx` file is, and then using the style as is from there? You would call the usual `Insert -> List / TOC -> BibTex Bibliography` menu and select the `acl2012` from the browse window. I didn't check this specific one thoroughly but it should work.

Answer (score 4):

The easy way:

1. Put the `.sty` file in the same folder which contains the `.lyx` file.
2. Open the `.lyx` file, go to Documents > Settings > LaTeX preamble.
3. Add this code:

   ```
   \usepackage{acl2012}
   ```
4. Click apply.

Regards

Comment: How is this different compared to the answer by `vaettchen`, apart from being shorter and missing some proper formatting?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Different technique. vaettchen's answer sets up a custom layout so you can select this, and that layout includes adding the package to the preamble. Mandrivagnome's answer just involves adding the package to the preamble (the part the user can modify).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Alright, accepted