# Cannot import .sty latex. CustomThesis.sty file not found

Tags: packages, lyx

I am trying to use the solution here [Converting sty and bst files to lyx layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77736/converting-sty-and-bst-files-to-lyx-layout) in order to import the sty files defined for the document type I need to write. I am actually writing my thesis. The files are available at http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/teaching/thesis/thesis-template-2012.zip, but I cannot find a way to use the .sty file in Lyx.

I have followed scrupulously answer cited before but I get the following error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2013.4.30)  9 JUL 2013 16:42
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**newfile2.tex
(./newfile2.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, lo
aded.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latin9.def
File: latin9.def 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
))

! LaTeX Error: File `LukeThesis.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.15 ^^M

*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 465 strings out of 495059
 4571 string characters out of 3182030
 47487 words of memory out of 3000000
 3725 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 4403 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,0n,17p,163b,37s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Anybody has some hints?

The LukeThesis.layout file in the ./lyx/layout folder is the following:

```
\DeclareLaTeXClass[report, LukeThesis.sty]{report (LukeThesis)}


Preamble     
    \usepackage{LukeThesis}
EndPreamble


Format 35
Input stdclass.inc
Input numreport.inc

Style Bibliography
    TopSep                4
    LabelString           "Bibliography"
    LabelFont
      Series              Bold
      Size                Huge
    EndFont
End
```

Comment: Where is `LukeThesis.sty`?

Comment: The LukeThesis.sty is in my the ./.lyx/layout/ directory

Comment: That's probably the wrong place. It should go in `\tex\latex\lukethesis` in your local texmf-tree (or in the current directory of your document (beside `newfile2.tex`) but I don't know what the current directory is if you use Lyx).

Comment: I am running ubuntu linux and I have installed lyx by sudo apt-get lyx, thus all with the default options. Where can I find the texmf-tree directory?

Comment: I have tried to put LukeThesis.sty in the same directory as the dummy file I am trying to compile and I got the following error

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.16 \usepackage
                [T1]{fontenc}                            %Set font encoding ...

The package inputenc has already been loaded with options:
  [latin9]

Comment: Try `Document | Settings | Language` and set the Encoding to `Other (no input enc)`. Not sure whether this resovles the conflict but worth a try.