# Writing a thesis in Lyx using a Latex Template - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: bibtex, lyx, templates, thesis

I'm looking to write my thesis in Lyx as I'm impressed with all the document handling features.

I have found, what is called, a Latex template for my university's thesis here: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/mice/c/d.php?d=109

The template contains a set of .tex, .bst. and .sty files as well as a simple Makefile. Running `make` does produce a nice pdf that looks exactly like a bare bones thesis would.

Now how can I get Lyx to play nice with all of this? For one, I don't see anything for dealing with Makefiles.

Am I shooting for the moon?

Comment: Somewhat similar question:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150887/using-a-new-document-class-template-with-lyx?lq=1  Regarding the Makefile: LyX generally does all the compilation runs automatically, so there's a chance you wont need it anyway.

Comment: It is somewhat similar but does not appear to help. In that post, the questioner is trying to deal with `.cls` files. The bulk of the files I have are `.tex`, with some `.bib`, `.sty`, and `.bst`. Also, the `.sty` file appears minor and seems to just be the style for in-text citations.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I guess I just assumed a custom class was used. I think you can just paste the stuff from `header.tex` into the preamble, maybe place the `.bst` in the same folder as the `.lyx` and choose that style from the list in LyX's GUI. Some stuff in the document itself may have to be placed in ERTs. I can try to make it work later, and then write an answer (but if anyone else wants to answer, please do).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the following should cover most things. If anything is missing or appears wrong, please let me know.

#### File organisation

Place `named.sty` and `named.bst` in the same folder as your `.lyx` file.

#### Document class options

Go to Document --> Settings --> Document class, choose *Report* from the list of classes, and add

```
11pt,openright,twoside,letterpaper
```

to the *Custom* options. (The template actually had `openright,oneside`, but the former has no effect with the latter, so I switched to `twoside`. I also removed the `onecolumn` option.)

[image]

#### Preamble

Paste the below code in Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble. Notes:

- You should of course modify the first three lines, adding your title, name and year.
- I removed the `epsfig` package, don't think it's normally used these days, and LyX loads `graphicx` (which is recommended for dealing with external images) anyway.
- I removed the `dvipdfm` and `letterpaper` options to `hyperref`. You'll probably compile with pdfLaTeX, making the first of these wrong. The latter is not used.
- I moved some stuff from the document to the preamble, including the definition of a pagestyle (`myplain`, I switched name from `plain`) and `\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}`.

  ```
  \newcommand{\thesistitle}{Thesis title}
  \newcommand{\thesisauthor}{Author's name}
  \newcommand{\thesisyear}{20XX}

  %%%
  %%% Packages
  %%%
  \usepackage{named}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \usepackage{afterpage}

  %
  % We use the hyperref package and customize it for optimal PDF 
  %
  \usepackage[
     pdftitle={\thesistitle},
     pdfauthor={\thesisauthor},
     pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
     bookmarks,
     bookmarksopen=true,
     pdfstartview={FitH},
     bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}

  %%%
  %%% Margins
  %%%
  \paperwidth=8.5in
  \paperheight=11in

  % 1in + hoffset + oddsidemargin + textwidth + marginparsep + marginparwidth
  % For PhD at Columbia we have single side theses and 1.5in left margin
  % The settings below leave 1.5 inch margin at the left and 1 inch at the right 
  % for US Letter paper
  \setlength{\hoffset}{0.0in}
  \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.5in}
  \setlength{\textwidth}{6in}
  \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0mm}

  % 1in + voffset + topmargin + headheight + headsep + textheight + footskip 
  % For PhD thesis we also need an extra inch at the bottom
  % 1inch = 72 pt
  \setlength{\voffset}{0.0in}
  \setlength{\topmargin}{.0in}
  \setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
  \setlength{\headsep}{22pt}
  \setlength{\textheight}{8.5in}
  \setlength{\footskip}{0pt}

  %%%
  %%% Spacing
  %%%
  \newcommand{\singlespace}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15} \small \normalsize}
  \newcommand{\oneandhalfspace}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3} \small \normalsize}
  \newcommand{\doublespace}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} \small \normalsize}
  \newcommand{\normalspace}{\doublespace}
  \footnotesep=1\baselineskip

  %%%
  %%% Counters depth
  %%%
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

  %%%
  %%% Title page.
  %%%
  \newcommand{\thesistitlepage}{
      \normalspace
      \thispagestyle{empty}
      \begin{center}
          \textbf{\LARGE \thesistitle} \\[1cm]
          \textbf{\LARGE \thesisauthor} \\[8cm]
          Submitted in partial fulfillment of the \\
          requirements for the degree \\
          of Doctor of Philosophy \\
          in the Graduate School of Arts and Sciences \\[4cm]
          \textbf{\Large COLUMBIA UNIVERSITY} \\[5mm]
          \thesisyear
      \end{center}
      \clearpage
  }

  %%%
  %%% Copyright page.
  %%%
  \newcommand{\thesiscopyrightpage}{
      \thispagestyle{empty}
      \strut \vfill
      \begin{center}
        \copyright \thesisyear \\
        \thesisauthor \\
        All Rights Reserved
      \end{center}
      \cleardoublepage
  }

  %%%
  %%% Abstract page.
  %%%
  \newcommand{\thesisabstract}{
      \thispagestyle{empty}
      \begin{center}
      \textbf{\LARGE ABSTRACT} \\[1cm]
       \textbf{\LARGE \thesistitle} \\[1cm]
       \textbf{\LARGE \thesisauthor} \\[1cm]
      \end{center}
      \input{abstract}
      \cleardoublepage
  }

  %%%
  %%% Miscellaneous
  %%%
  \newcommand{\draft}{
      \renewcommand{\normalspace}{\singlespace}
      \normalspace
      \chapter*{Draft. Version \today}
  \clearpage }


  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}


  % We change the pagestyle 
  \fancypagestyle{myplain} {%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
  \fancyhead[RE,LO]{\itshape \leftmark}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  }
  ```

#### In the document

1. Start by adding an ERT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) with

   ```
   % For the first pages we do not have numbering

   \pagestyle{empty}

   \thesistitlepage
   \thesiscopyrightpage
   \thesisabstract
   % In the "roman-numbered" section of the thesis, we have numbers at the bottom % and we have to reduce the textheight of the text to make space for the number
   \pagenumbering{roman}
   \pagestyle{plain}

   \setlength{\footskip}{0.5in}
   ```
2. After the ERT, add the table of contents, list of figures and list of tables via the Insert --> List/ToC menu.
3. Add an unnumbered chapter, call it *Acknowledgements* and write those here.

   (This is not exactly the same as in the template.)
4. If you want the dedication page, do the following:

   i. Do Insert --> Formatting --> Clear double page

   ii. Insert --> Formatting --> Vertical space. Choose VFill, check the box for *Protect*.

   iii. Write your dedication.

   iv. Add a second VFill, as step i).

   v. Insert --> Formatting --> Clear Double page
5. Add a new ERT with

   ```
   \pagenumbering{arabic}

   % In the "arabic" section of the thesis, we do not have numbers at  the
   % bottom and we want to use the full length of the page to avoid vbox 
   % underfulls. We use the fancyheaders package to adapt the headers 
   % according to the  Columbia requirements. 

   \setlength{\textheight}{8.5in}
   \setlength{\footskip}{0in}

   \pagestyle{myplain}
   ```
6. Write all your content.

#### Bibliography

Where the bibliography should be, do Insert --> List/ToC --> BibTeX bibliography. Select your `.bib` file, and from the *Style* drop down menu, choose *named*.

#### Complete example

The code below is actually a `.lyx` file, you can copy the text, save it as `something.lyx` and open it in LyX. It is generated by LyX 2.0.6, as LyX 2.1 isn't in Ubuntu's repositories yet, and I haven't bothered updating manually. (I never really use LyX anyway.)

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass report
\begin_preamble
\newcommand{\thesistitle}{Thesis title}
\newcommand{\thesisauthor}{Author's name}
\newcommand{\thesisyear}{20XX}

%%%
%%% Packages
%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{named}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{afterpage}

%
% We use the hyperref package and customize it for optimal PDF 
%
\usepackage[pdftitle={\thesistitle},pdfauthor={\thesisauthor},pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},letterpaper,bookmarks,bookmarksopen=true,pdfstartview={FitH},bookmarksnumbered=true,]{hyperref}

%%%
%%% Margins
%%%
\paperwidth=8.5in
\paperheight=11in

% 1in + hoffset + oddsidemargin + textwidth + marginparsep + marginparwidth
% For PhD at Columbia we have single side theses and 1.5in left margin
% The settings below leave 1.5 inch margin at the left and 1 inch at the right 
% for US Letter paper
\setlength{\hoffset}{0.0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0mm}

% 1in + voffset + topmargin + headheight + headsep + textheight + footskip 
% For PhD thesis we also need an extra inch at the bottom
% 1inch = 72 pt
\setlength{\voffset}{0.0in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{.0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{22pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.5in}
\setlength{\footskip}{0pt}

%%%
%%% Spacing
%%%
\newcommand{\singlespace}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15} \small \normalsize}
\newcommand{\oneandhalfspace}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3} \small \normalsize}
\newcommand{\doublespace}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} \small \normalsize}
\newcommand{\normalspace}{\doublespace}
\footnotesep=1\baselineskip

%%%
%%% Counters depth
%%%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

%%%
%%% Title page.
%%%
\newcommand{\thesistitlepage}{
    \normalspace
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{\LARGE \thesistitle} \\[1cm]
        \textbf{\LARGE \thesisauthor} \\[8cm]
        Submitted in partial fulfillment of the \\
        requirements for the degree \\
        of Doctor of Philosophy \\
        in the Graduate School of Arts and Sciences \\[4cm]
        \textbf{\Large COLUMBIA UNIVERSITY} \\[5mm]
        \thesisyear
    \end{center}
    \clearpage
}

%%%
%%% Copyright page.
%%%
\newcommand{\thesiscopyrightpage}{
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \strut \vfill
    \begin{center}
      \copyright \thesisyear \\
      \thesisauthor \\
      All Rights Reserved
    \end{center}
    \cleardoublepage
}

%%%
%%% Abstract page.
%%%
\newcommand{\thesisabstract}{
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
    \textbf{\LARGE ABSTRACT} \\[1cm]
     \textbf{\LARGE \thesistitle} \\[1cm]
     \textbf{\LARGE \thesisauthor} \\[1cm]
    \end{center}
    \input{abstract}
    \cleardoublepage
}

%%%
%%% Miscellaneous
%%%
\newcommand{\draft}{
    \renewcommand{\normalspace}{\singlespace}
    \normalspace
    \chapter*{Draft. Version \today}
\clearpage }


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}


% We change the pagestyle 
\fancypagestyle{myplain} {%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\itshape \leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\end_preamble
\options 11pt,openright,twoside,letterpaper,onecolumn
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

% For the first pages we do not have numbering
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
pagestyle{empty}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
thesistitlepage
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
thesiscopyrightpage
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
thesisabstract
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

% In the "roman-numbered" section of the thesis, we have numbers at the
 bottom % and we have to reduce the textheight of the text to make space
 for the number
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
pagenumbering{roman}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
pagestyle{plain}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
setlength{
\backslash
footskip}{0.5in}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset toc
LatexCommand tableofcontents

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset FloatList figure

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset FloatList table

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Chapter*
Acknowledgements
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
So long and thanks for all the fish.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Newpage cleardoublepage
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset VSpace vfill*
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\align center
Dedication
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset VSpace vfill*
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Newpage cleardoublepage
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
pagenumbering{arabic}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

% In the "arabic" section of the thesis, we do not have numbers at  the
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

% bottom and we want to use the full length of the page to avoid vbox 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

% underfulls.
 We use the fancyheaders package to adapt the headers 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

% according to the  Columbia requirements.

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
setlength{
\backslash
textheight}{8.5in}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
setlength{
\backslash
footskip}{0in}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
pagestyle{plain}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Chapter
Intro
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "chap:intro"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
This is about stuff.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Part
Stuff
\end_layout

\begin_layout Chapter
Something
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Etc.
\begin_inset CommandInset citation
LatexCommand cite
key "Grosz_and_Sidner_1986"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Part
Appendices
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset bibtex
LatexCommand bibtex
bibfiles "refs"
options "named"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: This is quite an improvement over anything I was able to put together. However, when I use your code in Lyx 2.1, copyright page is off centered. There is also a blank page between each section - that is between the ToC and the List of Figures, between each chapter and each part. Do you know how I could correct this?

Comment: @User7391 Remove `twoside` from the class options. Note that the template was a little inconsistent here, so I don't know what is 'correct'. They had `openright,oneside`. The former indicates that all chapters (which includes ToC, LoT, LoF) should open on a right hand side, while the latter indicates that the document should be set up for one sided printing, effectively removing the distinction between left and right pages. The use of `\cleardoublepage` might indicate that two-sided printing should be used, where the margins are asymmetrical, which is why I changed from `oneside` to `twoside`.