# How to include child documents in Lyx

Tags: lyx

I am new to LaTeX and LyX. For writing my thesis I got 2 files from university: `uw_masters_thesis.sty` and `sample_thesis.tex`. The sample file contains `\usepackage{uw_masters_thesis}` in preamble. If I use LaTex I simply put both files in same directory and include child documents by using `\include` or `\input` in the `sample_thesis.tex` document.
The `embedded objects` manual in LyX suggests to specify the `Document Class` of master document in child document. But in my case the document class is `Report (Standard Class)`. In my understanding, what uses the style file is the `\usepackage{uw_masters_thesis}` in preamble.
I am creating thesis chapters (child documents) in lyx without specifying any thing in Document Stettings. I want them to use the style provided by `.sty` file and finally include all of them in master document. How can I achieve this in Lyx. Please suggest a step by step solution.

Comment: please wait much longer than 2 hours to cross-post, and if you do cross-post, put the links from each post to each other. (thank you for mentioning that you did post on Stack Exchange on the LyX list though). Here is the LyX mailing list link: http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg99201.html

Comment: Could you give some feedback on my answer below (upvote and/or accept if it is useful, comment if not)? If you provide a link to the files (`uw_masters_thesis.sty` and `sample_thesis.tex`) it will be much easier to give specific advice. (The same goes for your question about Harvard style, it is nice to get feedback on whether an answer is helpful or not.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the only thing you need to do is to place the `.sty` file in the same folder as your `.lyx` file, and then go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble, and add `\usepackage{uw_masters_thesis}`. You probably need to do this for each child document.

(This could depend on how `sample_thesis.tex` is set up as well. See [Writing a thesis in Lyx using a Latex Template - What am I doing wrong?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181310/writing-a-thesis-in-lyx-using-a-latex-template-what-am-i-doing-wrong/181358#181358) for an example of a similar situation.)