# Installing New Doc Classes in Lyx

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I have been following  the instructions for installing a new  doc class in lyx but when I open up lyx under *document - settings  -  document class* my doc class appears under unvailable. So what's gone wrong? I must  have done something right since the document class is recognised in the list.
Grateful for your help and advice. I have to say the procedure works perfectly in previous versions of lyx.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Have you reconfigured LyX (Tools > Reconfigure)?

Comment: See [Using a new document class/template with LyX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150887/5764)

Comment: of course i reconfigured. I followed the riht procedure.

Comment: could it be my layout file is unsuitable? As I said it does apear in the doc class list  in Lyx  but as unavailable which might be a clue. What does unavailable mean as applied to other doc classes in the list