# Trouble adding new .layout to LyX based on .cls

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I'm having problem with transformation of .cls to .layout of the [IACAS format](http://iacas.technion.ac.il/author-instructions/). I tried using [Using a new document class/template with LyX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150887/using-a-new-document-class-template-with-lyx/151183#151183?newreg=7be1f56e35b743cb877e29996385f3ac). I wish I could ask the question there but the on-site popups suggested me to create a new question.

I started by doing steps 1-5 successfully on windows 7 – MiKteX install. However, when I tried to add everything which in  the .cls file to the Preamble-EndPreamble section of the iacas.layout file I get the error in the picture. It does not matter whether I use a new document or an existing one (with class changed). So obviously something that I put to the  Preamble-EndPreamble section should not be there. How should I proceed so I would have both lyx working and the required options available?

[image]

Thanks a lot,

Rami

Comment: After removing the

\AtBeginDocument
\endinput

at the end of the .layout. It worked! Maybe you might want to add it to the thread for future users to use.