# IEEEtran class is unavailable in Lyx?

Tags: lyx

I have installed Lyx. But the document class IEEEtran is unavailable. When I open a .lyx document I receive: "The selected document class IEEE Transaction requires external files that are not available, etc" 
After installing I reconfigured from tools in Lyx but it didn't resolve the issue.
Also, when I export the .lyx document as pdf, it shows that export was successful but no file is generated. 
I'm on Windows 7 and have MikTex 2.9 inatalled.
What should be done?

Comment: what is your operating system and TeX distribution? How did you install the class file?

Comment: I've edited my post. Also, all of the document classes in Lyx are grayed out and show unavailable.

Comment: Are you able to compile a file outside of LyX? I've often seen this problem on Windows but I've never run into it on Ubuntu so I might not be of much help.

Comment: Related: [Using a new document class/template with LyX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150887/5764)