# Installing IOP Conference Series to LyX

Tags: lyx, document-classes

I've a problem to get the IOP Conference Series template working with LyX. What I managed to do so far:

1. Download the necessary files from [IOP Author Guidelines](https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/author-guidelines-for-conference-proceedings/)
2. Install the files like explained in [IOP Article Class Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061189/how-to-install-the-iop-institute-of-physics-latex-document-class-for-texlive-a)

After that I'm able to compile the example file, so the installation to the TeX distribution worked. The thing I'm missing now, is a LyX ".layout" file to make the class available in LyX. I'm not familiar how to write these files - I tried to adept the file for the IOP article (provided by LyX) but failed. Could somebody provide a working ".layout" file for the IOP conference series class?

(I use MacTeX 2016, LyX 2.2.3)

Comment: There's no simple way to write a .layout file. It takes a lot of time. You would have to read through Help > Customization and study the .layout files that LyX comes with.

Comment: writing a layout file if you already have a latex cls file is not complicated at all. check out these instructions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150887/using-a-new-document-class-template-with-lyx